# In terminal 'tns preview' command not working. (NativeScript)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I wanted to run my NS application in local. I downloaded project from play.nativescript.org, And I open cmd with target path and I followed this steps

> Step 1. Install the latest NativeScript CLI
>
> Type the following command in a Command Prompt or Terminal.
>
> `npm install -g nativescript@latest`

and I have successfully installed the NativeScript CLI

> Step 2. Preview your app
>
> Navigate to your project folder and run the following command to start
> previewing your app.
>
> `tns preview`

When I entered the command I get this errors

```
You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.
npm WARN deprecated bfj-node4@5.3.1: Switch to the `bfj` package for fixes and new features!
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/thomasconner/javascript/tarball/67b7944366453a87226389d483ac1ad861e0e129npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'pubnub@https://github.com/thomasconner/javascript/tarball/67b7944366453a87226389d483ac1ad861e0e129' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'kinvey-nativescript-sdk'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dotor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-01T09_47_56_177Z-debug.log
Command npm.cmd failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As in github.com **therosko** has written, making `kinvey-nativescript-sdk` version as `5.0.1` worked for me. Src: [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/playground-feedback/issues/190#issuecomment-678443301)

Comment: I think you meant to enter a link description but this is the correct github issue w/ useful context

Comment: I was facing the same issue and this worked. Simply updating the version works. I think people facing this issue are exporting the code from NativeScript directly which comes with this old reference (this is what I did, oops). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, play.nativescript.org exported projects won't run with nativescript version 7 and up.

Currently, the only solution would be to install {N} CLI using `npm install -g nativescript@6.8.0`

Comment: Do you have more info on this & if so can you please explain further? Why would NS Playground / Preview encourage you to write an app that you can't build? It even prompts you to run `tns preview` when you download the app source.